# How is the min heap being created?

Tags: java, heap

In the code a stream of strings are given and we are returning the k longest strings in the stream. My question is how does the comparator work? I understand that we are using an anonymous function to override the compare method to compare the length of two strings but how does this comparison create a min heap?

```
public static List<String> topK(int k, Iterator<String> iter) {
PriorityQueue<String> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<>(k, new Comparator<String>() {
   public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
     return Integer.compare(s1.length(), s2.length());  
   }
});
while (iter.hasNext()) {
  minHeap.add(iter.next());
  if (minHeap.size() > k) {
    // Remove the shortest string. Note that the comparison function above
    // will order the strings by length.
    minHeap.poll();
  }
}
return new ArrayList<>(minHeap);
}
```

Comment: Have you read the javadoc for PriorityQueue?  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're asking. The question "how does this comparison create a min heap" is non-sensical. The comparison *doesn't* create a min heap. The `PriorityQueue` code creates a min heap by using the comparator you provided to order the items in the heap. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Javadoc of `PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html):

> The head of this queue is the least element with respect to the specified ordering.

And [`PriorityQueue.poll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#poll--):

> Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, or returns null if this queue is empty.

The comparator sorts elements by increasing length, so the head of the queue is the one with the smallest length. As such, when you invoke `poll()`, the shortest string is removed from the queue.

If you pop so as only to keep at most `k` items in the queue, those will be the `k` longest items taken from the iterator so far. Once the iterator is exhausted, those will be the (at most) `k` longest items.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to summarize in easy words

Binary heap is a special type of tree data structure behind the binary queue. In a heap, each node and their child nodes follow some common pattern. For example, in a min heap, all the child nodes must be greater than the parent node. So as a result, the root node holds the smallest number.

In a heap, when there is any change in the heap (insert, delete, update), then the heap is restructured in a way, such that the common priniciple is maintained (e.g., in above case the parent remains always smaller than its children). So when some operation is done on the heap, a heapify operation is called. SO for the min-heap, a min-heapify will be called to maintain the principle. So in a min-heapify operation, the parents will be compared with the child nodes recursively to check which one has the lower value, and if the child has lower value, then it will be swapped with the parents.

Now in you case, you are just implementing this compare method of heapify operation. So for max heap you will just do the opposite (setting higher value as parent). Also, you can implement you custom compare method by satisfying your own need.

To learn more details, you can search with binary heap, and you can find plenty of good resources out there.